# Modular exponentiation commutativity in Diffie-Hellman

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, cryptography

I've been learning about [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) key exchange.

One of the main tricks comes down to a commutativity property of exponentiation in the relevant modular arithmetic, it seems.

Something like:

(**EDIT:** As noted by [@Ted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580583/modular-exponentiation-commutativity-in-diffie-hellman/1580619?noredirect=1#comment3217370_1580583), I got the formula wrong, hence my confusion.)

$$r^{A^B} \equiv r^{AB} \equiv \; ... \; \equiv r^{B^A} \pmod p$$

I know that this is not true in general, so presumably derives from the particular choices of `r`, `A`, `B`, and `p`.

I've done a fair amount of searching around, but cannot find a proof, or even a reasonable explanation of where this property arises from.

Can anyone here help?

Comment: It is true for all integers r,A,B and p

Comment: @MayankDeora: How about `r=2`, `A=2`, `B=3`, `p=1000`? I get $2^{2^3} \equiv 2^8 \equiv 256 \pmod {1000} \ne 2^{3^2} \equiv 2^9 \equiv 512 \pmod {1000} \ne 2^{3*2} \equiv 2^6 \equiv 64 \pmod {1000}$

Comment: @jwd  You have the order of operations wrong.  The relevant identity for Diffie-Helman is $(r^A)^B = (r^B)^A$, not $r^{(A^B)} = r^{(B^A)}$.

Comment: @Ted: Ohhhhh (: Thank you.

Comment: @jwd i have proved the identity as told by Ted

Answer (score 2):

We have to prove that
$$({r^A} \bmod{p})^B \bmod{p} = (r^B \bmod{p})^A \bmod{p} = (r^{AB})  \bmod{p}$$

We would use binomial expansion for it.

Let $r = xp + y$, then $(r) \bmod{p} = y$.

As we know that:
$$r^A = (xp + y)^A = {}_A C_0(xp)^A + {}_A C_1(xp)^{A-1}(y)^{1} + \cdots + {}_A C_n(y)^A$$

If we calculate $\bmod{p}$ of the above term we would get
$$(r^A) \bmod{p} = 0 + 0 + \cdots + (y^A) \bmod{p} = (y^A) \bmod{p}$$

Similarly, let
$y^A = \alpha p + \beta$, then $(y^A) \bmod{p} = \beta$. We have:
$$((r^A) \bmod{p})^B \bmod{p}=((y^A) \bmod{p})^B \bmod{p} = (\beta)^B \bmod{p}$$

Now we would calculate $r^{AB} \bmod{p}$.

$$r^{AB} \bmod{p} = (xp + y)^{AB} \bmod{p} = y^{AB} \bmod{p} \\ 
= (y^A)^B \bmod{p} = (\alpha p + \beta)^B \bmod{p} = (\beta)^B \bmod{p}$$

i.e.$$((r^A) \bmod{p})^B \bmod{p} = (r^{AB}) \bmod{p} = ((r^B) \bmod{p})^A \bmod{p}$$
-Hence proved

Comment: This is fine and all, but wouldn't it be simpler to note that (${r^A})^B = {r^A}\cdot{r^A}\cdot{r^A}\ldots = r^{A+A+A\ldots} = r^{A\cdot B}$ ?

Comment: I think that you should edit your question.

Comment: Good point; edited.